# console.log not working in JS file

Tags: javascript, extjs, syntax

I am trying to debug a JavaScript file within a larger project and for some reason, the console.log() is not outputting anything to my console view. I have tried other functions such as alert() as well but they have also given me the same results.

Here is my code:

```
Ext.define('chefRoleSetupFormPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    id: 'chefRoleSetupFormPanel',

    title: 'Role Information',
    url: 'chefCreateRole.php',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'roleName',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        allowBlank: false,
        anchor: '100%'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textareafield',
        grow: true,
        name: 'roleDescription',
        fieldLabel: 'Description',
        anchor: "100% 75%"
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Reset',
        handler: function() {
            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Submit',
        formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
        disabled: true,
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    success: function(form, action) {
                        var roleSetupForm = Ext.getCmp('chefRoleSetupFormPanel');
                        roleSetupForm = roleSetupForm.getForm();

                        var roleName = roleSetupForm.findField('roleName')['value'];
                        var roleDescription = roleSetupForm('roleDescription')['value'];

                        var chefRequiredCookbooksGrid = Ext.getCmp('chefRequiredCookbooksGrid');
                        var runList = chefRequiredCookbooksGrid.getStore().getRange();  

                        console.log(runList);


                        roleSetupForm.submit({
                            params: {
                                roleName: roleName,
                                roleDescription: roleDescription,
                                runList: JSON.stringify(runList)
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    failure: function(form, action) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Did you test to see if the function was hitting `failure` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to log in the failure. You might have an error you are not catching.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry, it was actually the error message coming in from my PHP script telling me the request was not made. I removed the call to the script and am still unable to perform the console.log()

Comment: You must still have an error somewhere. Keep on logging that failure. Are you sure that `form.isValid()` ?

Answer (score 1):

console.log() is great but I would suggest to use Ext.log(...).

This is just a best practice I was suggested to follow.

Usage:

```
Ext.log({level:'debug'}, 'Message Here');
```